# How to resolve Vapor MongoProvider build errors using XCode 8.1 and Swift 3.0.1?

Tags: xcode, mongodb, vapor

I have just update my Xcode from version 8.0 to 8.1 and Swift 3.0.1.

And if I set 'mongo-provider' package dependency in Package.swift:

```
.Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/mongo-provider.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 0)
```

I have a build errors in Terminal output:

```
Fetching Dependencies [Failed]
Check your dependencies' Package.swift files to see where the conflict is.
Error: warning: refname '1.0.0' is ambiguous.
warning: refname '1.0.0' is ambiguous.
warning: refname '1.0.4' is ambiguous.
warning: refname '1.0.4' is ambiguous.
warning: refname '1.7.2' is ambiguous.
warning: refname '1.7.2' is ambiguous.
warning: refname '3.7.2' is ambiguous.
warning: refname '3.7.2' is ambiguous.
swift-package: error: The dependency graph could not be satisfied. The package (https://github.com/vapor/socks.git) with version tag in range (1.0.0..<1.0.9223372036854775807) is not found. Found tags ([1.1.0])
```

Do you have any ideas to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by run `vapor clean` before `vapor build` or `vapor xcode` command

Comment: Hi! Cold you check what am I missing connecting to `Mlab` from `Vapor`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463706/how-to-connect-to-mlab-in-vapor